# Create fixed cell in Master Sheet in Excel to retrieve data from the multiple sheets

Tags: excel

I have an excel file with many sheets named as: ABC, DEF, GHI,... with the same data frame structure inside, for example:

```
CR    1  2  3
Data  5  6  7
```

I need to create a Master sheet in which I have a cell that I could fill name into. I need that when I fill the name of one sheet, the Master sheet will populate the same data from child sheet to master sheet. For example, when I fill the ABC name in the cell, the Master sheet will retrieve all the data from sheet ABC to the master sheet. How could it be done?

Answer (score 0):

Say we always want the data from cell **B9** in some sheet.  Place the sheet name in cell **A1**, and in **B1** enter:

```
=INDIRECT(A1&"!B9")
```

For example:

[image]

Comment: Thank you, but if I need to have all data from that sheet, how could I do it in an easy way, such as drag down then all the data in sheet name A1 will appear in master sheet?